# Z-index issue with tooltip in IE7

Tags: css, z-index, internet-explorer-7

I have a tooltip popup with a z-index at the highest level. When the user clicks the tooltip in IE7, it displays under content on the page, instead of above it. This issue is only occuring in IE7.

```
.tipBody {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: -18px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details, such as some HTML and more CSS? Just because your `z-index` is high doesn't mean it's following the z flow of the document.

Comment: The relative position may be screwing you up.  Can you reproduce your problem [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try adding !important after the property value, like this:

```
.tipBody {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-top: -18px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, positioned elements follow a different stacking order. You can usually fix it by giving the parent of your element a higher z-index.

I suggest you read the following link, it gives you a good explanation about the issue, and how you can solve it.

http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Hope this helped.